# Value of select box after ajax on change function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, select

I have a select box that on change is displaying another select box with ajax, but the problem is that my PHP form don't take any value of second select box. 
There is some of my code.

So this is my ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=link]").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"fns/site.php",
            data:$("#formm").serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                $("#link").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Form that i supposed to get all the values:

```
<table>
<form method="get" id="formm">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="link">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Select</option>
            <option value="0" disabled>Site</option>
                <option class="sub" value="1">Link 1</option>
                <option class="sub" value="2">Link 2</option>
            <option value="3">Link 3</option>   
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="link">

</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

And site.php file:

```
$site=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `site`");
echo '<td><select name="site">';
echo '<option value="0">Select</option>';
while($site1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($site)){
    echo '
        <option value="'.$site1['id'].'">'.$site1['title'].'</option>
    ';
}
echo '</select></td>';
```

So after all i don't have a value of "site" select box...

Comment: do not use mysql_* it is decrecated. Use pdo or mysqli_* instead. Did you check you have data in site table ?

Comment: take everything into one variable and echo it.

Comment: what means you don't have a value of "site"-checkbox ?

Comment: Yes I heve. Ajax display a select box with all the options but after submiting I don't have any values of this select box.

Comment: i don't have a value of select box with name site :)

Comment: Did you connect mysql database connection in ajax page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so someone suggested that I should get rid of table and use `<label>` to format a form.
So that's all :)

Form should look like this:

```
<form method="get" id="formm">
<label></label>
    <select name="link">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select</option>
        <option value="0" disabled>Site</option>
            <option class="sub" value="1">Link 1</option>
            <option class="sub" value="2">Link 2</option>
        <option value="3">Link 3</option>   
    </select>
<div id="link">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ajax function if your site.php file don't use the value of link in sql condition?

You could use just a simple css display, like this:

```html
<table>
<form method="get" id="formm">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="link">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Select</option>
            <option value="0" disabled>Site</option>
                <option class="sub" value="1">Link 1</option>
                <option class="sub" value="2">Link 2</option>
            <option value="3">Link 3</option>   
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="link">
    <td>
        <select name="site" id="site" style="display:none;">
            <option value="0">Select</option>  
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

And in ajax function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=link]").change(function(){
        $("#site").css("display", "");
    });
});
```

Comment: But I want to take different select boxes with different names so that's why I'm using Ajax